# Change Properties of Sliding Tab Layout

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, pagerslidingtabstrip, android-tablayout

In the Image below
[image]

Quetion 1:
I want to change the color of Blue color underbar and the text color of Text (eg. FlashCards) in Sliding Tab Layout.

How can I change that?
Also I want to change the space coming after Name : 'MyAccount'

Question 2:
When I slide the Tab,the heading at the top of toolbar(Flashcards) should change.
Any Idea how to do that.
My XML File for layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_home_screeen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/windowBackground"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/back_title"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<com.example.ojasjuneja.chem.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tab"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</com.example.ojasjuneja.chem.SlidingTabLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add PagerSlidingTabStrip in your XML

```
<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

and in java file add below code..

```
  PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            tabs.setViewPager(view_pager);
            tabs.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            tabs.setIndicatorColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.sky_blue_color));
```

Comment: add dependancy in your gradle file 
 compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.0'

Answer (score 0):

> Question 2 When i slide the Tab,the heading at the top of toolbar(Flashcards) should change. Any Idea how to do that. My XML File for layout looks like this:

You need to add one line in each fragment below OnCreate() for example

My List Fragment

```
((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("MY LISTS");
```

My Account Fragment

```
((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Account");
```